# Keeping OpenBSD up-to-date with openup

Tags: upgrade, openbsd

I installed OpenBSD 5.6 -RELEASE on a machine, and then kept it up to date with [M:tier's openup](https://stable.mtier.org/).

Is my machine now considered up-to-date, the same way as it would be if I where following the -STABLE branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is up-to-date in the same way as you would following the -STABLE branch